Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account : Anchor Tip Program Error
here is the code, the error occurs in withdraw function, i used program ( tip program ) itself as authority:
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

use anchor_spl::token::{transfer, Mint, Token, TokenAccount, Transfer};

declare_id!("25vzWQFcgHbthsBhjNEaa6BGrQqCh6YtAFAa4QzKC4su");

pub const PROGRAM_SEED: &str = "program_seed";
pub const TIP_SEED: &str = "tip_seed";

#[error_code]
pub enum TipError {
    #[msg("The tip has already been claimed.")]
    AlreadyClaimed,
    #[msg("Tip amount can't be 0")]
    InvalidTipAmount,
    #[msg("Invalid withdrawl amount -> can't be 0")]
    InvalidWithdrawAmount,
}

#[program]
mod tip {
    use super::*;

    pub fn give_tip(ctx: Context<GiveTip>, _receiver: Pubkey, amount: u64) -> Result<()> {
        // Ensure the tip hasn't been claimed already
        if amount <= 0 {
            return Err(TipError::InvalidTipAmount.into());
        }

        let signer = &ctx.accounts.signer;

        let from_ata = &ctx.accounts.from_ata;

        let to_ata = &ctx.accounts.to_ata;

        let token_program = &ctx.accounts.token_program;

        let record_pda = &mut ctx.accounts.record_pda;

        // Transfer tokens from taker to initializer
        let cpi_accounts = Transfer {
            from: from_ata.to_account_info(),
            to: to_ata.to_account_info(),
            authority: signer.to_account_info().clone(),
        };

        let cpi_program = token_program.to_account_info();

        let cpi_context = CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts);

        match transfer(cpi_context, amount) {
            Ok(_) => {
                msg!("Tokens transferred successfully");
            }
            Err(error) => {
                msg!("Failed to transfer tokens: {:?}", error);
                return Err(error.into());
            }
        }

        record_pda.amount += amount;

        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn withdraw_tip(ctx: Context<WithdrawTip>) -> Result<()> {
        let record_pda = &mut ctx.accounts.record_pda;
        // Ensure the tip hasn't been claimed already
        msg!("pda amound {}", record_pda.amount.to_string());

        if record_pda.amount <= 0 {
            return Err(TipError::InvalidWithdrawAmount.into());
        }

        let amount = record_pda.amount;

        let from_ata = &ctx.accounts.from_ata;
        let to_ata = &ctx.accounts.to_ata;
        let token_program = &ctx.accounts.token_program;
        let signer = &ctx.accounts.signer;

        let program = &ctx.accounts.program;

        msg!("owner is -> {}", program.key().to_string());
        // Transfer tokens from taker to initializer
        let cpi_accounts = Transfer {
            from: from_ata.to_account_info(),
            to: to_ata.to_account_info(),
            authority: program.to_account_info().clone(),
        };

        let cpi_program = token_program.to_account_info();
        let cpi_context = CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts);

        match transfer(cpi_context, amount) {
            Ok(_) => {
                msg!("Tokens transferred successfully");
            }
            Err(error) => {
                msg!("Failed to transfer tokens: {:?}", error);
                return Err(error.into());
            }
        }

        record_pda.amount = 0;

        Ok(())
    }

}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(receiver:Pubkey, amount: u64)]
pub struct GiveTip<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub from_ata: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    #[account(mut,  associated_token::mint = mint,   associated_token::authority = tip_program )]
    pub to_ata: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    pub tip_program: AccountInfo<'info>,

    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,

    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,

    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = signer,
        space = 8 + 8, 
        seeds = [PROGRAM_SEED.as_bytes(), &receiver.key().to_bytes(), TIP_SEED.as_bytes()],
        bump,
    )]
    pub record_pda: Account<'info, Tip>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct WithdrawTip<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [PROGRAM_SEED.as_bytes(), &signer.key().to_bytes(), TIP_SEED.as_bytes()],
        bump,
    )]
    pub record_pda: Account<'info, Tip>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub from_ata: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub to_ata: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    pub program: AccountInfo<'info>,

    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
}

#[account]
pub struct Tip {
    pub amount: u64,
}

and here is the solpg test:
import {
  createMint,
  createAssociatedTokenAccount,
  mintTo,
  TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
} from "@solana/spl-token";
import { BN } from "@project-serum/anchor";
import { PublicKey, Signer } from "@solana/web3.js";
import assert from "assert";

// Assuming 'pg' is an object that provides access to program, connection, and wallet
describe("Community Tipping Program", () => {
  let mint: PublicKey,
    signer: Signer,
    fromAta: PublicKey,
    toAta: PublicKey,
    receiver: PublicKey,
    tipPDA: PublicKey;

  before(async () => {
    signer = pg.wallet.keypair;

    receiver = pg.wallets.wallet2.publicKey; // Receiver's public key

    mint = await createMint(
      pg.program.provider.connection,
      signer,
      pg.wallet.publicKey,
      null,
      0
    );

    fromAta = await createAssociatedTokenAccount(
      pg.program.provider.connection,
      signer,
      mint,
      pg.wallet.publicKey
    );

    toAta = await createAssociatedTokenAccount(
      pg.program.provider.connection,
      signer,
      mint,
      pg.PROGRAM_ID
    );

    // Mint some tokens to the sender's ATA
    await mintTo(
      pg.program.provider.connection,
      signer,
      mint,
      fromAta,
      signer.publicKey,
      1000
    );

    [tipPDA] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
      [
        Buffer.from("program_seed"),
        receiver.toBuffer(),
        Buffer.from("tip_seed"),
      ],
      pg.PROGRAM_ID
    );
    console.log("tip pda ", tipPDA.toBase58());
  });

  it("should give tips successfully", async () => {
    const tipAmount = new BN(500);

    const txHash = await pg.program.methods
      .giveTip(pg.wallets.wallet2.publicKey, tipAmount)
      .accounts({
        signer: pg.wallet.publicKey,
        fromAta,
        toAta,
        mint,
        tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        recordPda: tipPDA,
        tipProgram: pg.PROGRAM_ID,
        systemProgram: web3.SystemProgram.programId,
      })
      .signers([pg.wallet.keypair])
      .rpc();

    console.log(
      `Transaction URL: https://solscan.io/tx/${txHash}?cluster=devnet`
    );

    const tokenAtaAccount =
      await pg.program.provider.connection.getTokenAccountBalance(toAta);
    assert.strictEqual(
      tokenAtaAccount.value.uiAmount,
      tipAmount.toNumber(),
      "The receiver's token account should have the transferred tokens"
    );
  });

  it("should withdraw tips successfully", async () => {
    const txHash = await pg.program.methods
      .withdrawTip()
      .accounts({
        signer: pg.wallets.wallet2.publicKey,
        fromAta: toAta,
        toAta: fromAta,
        tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        recordPda: tipPDA,
        program: pg.PROGRAM_ID,
      })
      .signers([pg.wallets.wallet2.keypair])
      .rpc();

    console.log(
      `Transaction URL: https://solscan.io/tx/${txHash}?cluster=devnet`
    );

    const tokenAtaAccount =
      await pg.program.provider.connection.getTokenAccountBalance(toAta);
    assert.strictEqual(
      tokenAtaAccount.value.uiAmount,
      0,
      "The receiver's token account should be empty after withdrawal"
    );
  });
});


